# Django development server: templates render from custom views not getting static media

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a development server running (and serving content) using the built in django server. All my templates that are rendered from generic views point correctly to the static media files (css/java/imgs) but ones that are rendered via custom views don't seem to prepend the /media/ folder to the urls. (At least this seems to be the problem)

In my settings I have:

```
DJANGO_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DB_PATH = os.path.join( (os.path.split(DJANGO_PATH))[0] , 'db/dev.db')
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join( DJANGO_PATH , 'templates')
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join( (os.path.split(DJANGO_PATH))[0] , 'media')
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_PATH
```

and In my urls I have an entry

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
```

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Ooops, forgot to mention. All my templates inherit from a base template which has all the media files like:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/some/file.css
```

So in my templates folder I have:

```
/templates/base.html
/templates/someapp/childtemplate.html
```

with all the css/js in the header like above. Then in the templates specific to my applicaiton I am simply inheriting the base template

**Furthermore**
I can view the media by visiting

```
localhost:8000/media/
```

no problem, so the urlCONF seems to be doing it's job

Comment: But what are you doing in your template? How are you outputting the path to the media files?

Comment: I've edited the original. I have all my templates inheriting from the base template (which has the paths in the header). This works fine for generic views and templates, but not for custom ones?

Comment: Fixed thanks to the answers below. For anyone reading this in the future, have a read of the article provided in Omer's answer as it it a great concise summary of Context Processors and why Generic Views add them by default, while custom views need to call them specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, MEDIA_URL is not accessible by default from the template context.
The easiest workaround is to create a new template context processor:

```
def media_url(request):
    from django.conf import settings
    return {'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL}
```

And in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('myapp.context_processors.media_url',)
```

Just remember to use the `RequestContext` when rendering the template. In the view:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
return render_to_response("my_app/my_template.html", {'some_var': 'foo'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Your templates should now render correctly.

For more on this:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that  `django.core.context_processors.media` is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in settings.py. This enables the use of `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in your templates.

Edit: As Daniel pointed out, I forgot to mention that yes, in order to take advantage of your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` you need to pass `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to the `render_to_response` function in your view. Some alternatives to having to do that for every view are to use the `render_to()` decorator in the `django-annoying` third-party app, or to just import and use `direct_to_template` instead of `render_to_response`, which is a neat trick in that it automatically uses the `RequestContext`.

Comment: I forgot about django.core.context_processors.media. This is, of course, better than what I've suggested.

Comment: You still need to ensure you use `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` as noted in Omer's answer below.

Comment: Having django.core.context_processors.media in the settings, along with Omer's answer has solved it. If I was using a production server, the media would be dealth with by apache/cherokee. I presume this would mean I wouldn't need the django context processor for dealing with media?

Comment: Yes you still need the context processor in production. The context processor, along with using RequestContext, is how you get {{ MEDIA_URL }} into your templates.